# Rails - Devise - prevent redirecting after sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am going to make "Register" button work after signing in, too, but it redirects to root path when I click the button.

I think it is because of filter.

RegistrationController code:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :after_registration ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource
    render_with_scope :new
  end
...
```

And the url for registration page is /users/sign_up

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` change with that as it should be inherited from devise

Comment: what should happen if a sigined in user clicks on register. Should he than register another user? Or should he edit his own registration profile?

Comment: no, if a signed user clicks on register, it doesn't go to register page. It goes home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. This is happening because of the [:require_no_authentication](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v2.2/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L117) method. It assures that the user is not authenticated and redirects the user if he is.

I suppose in your case you can just remove this before filter.